# create column by looking not null values in other columns

Tags: python, pandas, series

I am trying to create a column in my dataframe which searches each column and checks if the value of at specific row is null or not, if it is not the new column will contain this value, otherwise it will skip it. It is not possible that two columns contains a non null value.

For example:

```
  A   B   C   D   E
NaN NaN NaN NaN   a 
  b NaN NaN NaN NaN
NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

My expected output:

```
  A   B   C   D   E  new_column
NaN NaN NaN NaN   a           a
  b NaN NaN NaN NaN           b
NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN         NaN
```

Comment: Do you mean `df.max(1)`?

Comment: Why is the third row of `new_column` `nan` instead of `d`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `bfill` horizontally and then select the first column:

```
df['new_column'] = df.bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0]
```

Output:

```
>>> df
     A   B   C   D    E new_column
0  NaN NaN NaN NaN    a          a
1    b NaN NaN NaN  NaN          b
2  NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN        NaN
```

Comment: `new_column` is bringing me all null values in all cases by doing max :(

Comment: Sorry about the delay, I got confused. Check now @Lucas ;)